# I am building a mule4 custom connector using SDK.How do i get the reference of mule message object in the operations class?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

This is my operation class,

```
 //@Inject
 //protected CoreEvent coreEvent;

@Execution(ExecutionType.BLOCKING)
public void logging(String message, String category, Classification classification){
  try{
   if(message.isEmpty()){
   /*I need to print the contents of #[message](message containing 
       the attributes, payload and vars)
      }
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Classification is an enum class.

```
public enum Classification {
PERFORMANCE, TECHNICAL, FUNCTIONAL
}
```

The CoreEvent is an super Interface, injecting an interface is not possible. Tried couple of other classes like DefaultMessageBuilder.

But there was no luck.
I need to get the reference of MuleMessage by auto injecting or some way, i am not sure how to do it.

May i know what i am missing, i need to get reference of muleMessage and print its contents in case of empty. To elaborate a bit I mean when we use normal mule provided logger component with empty message, we gets printed the message attributes, payloads, variables. The same functionality is needed in my custom mule4 sdk connector, As i am building based on classification, Where classification would be drop down describing 3 options. This is requirement is for Mule4.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that operations can not access the event, neither they can access to variables nor attributes. By design all the information needed for the operation should be passed as parameters. Also the operation can return a single result, which the runtime assigns to the payload or a variable by configuration.

A possible alternative would to pass the variables and attributes to a logging operation as parameters, though it would be more manual than just using an operation.

Comment: Yes i got it. but i am trying to implement custom logger in mule4 using SDK. My aim is to print the entire message( when provided empty in message field, the attributes, variables and payload has to be printed). I want to inject or autowire this muleMessage object and check if message field provided in logger is empty, then use the muleMessage Object and print the contents. Hope you got it. I am not using coreEvent any More, as it is an super interface and mule will not allow to inject this. Can i know which is the suitable method to inject/autowire the muleMessage in my custom connector ????

Comment: Maybe the question doesn't match the need. The problem you want to resolve is to get the Message, but the error mentioned was due to trying to return a Message. Please update the question to focus on the right problem.

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know in case u need further details. Waiting for ur reply.

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks. I don't have an answer at hand. I'll update my answer if I find one.

Comment: Yes please. I am searching for this from past 1 week. Please let me know as soon as possible.. I will be waiting for the answer.

Comment: Yes please. I am searching for this from past 1 week. Let me know as soon as possible.. I am waiting for this.

Comment: I updated the answer. It is not possible.

Comment: As i see default behaviour of operations, is whatever we pass in parameters to a method function would be displayed as gui fields. 


I want just message, category and classification to be displayed . Any work around to send this paramters as non gui field or what could be alternative way ?

Please let me know on this, how do we inject this field or any way to get this values.

Comment: I'm not aware of a method to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way in documentation, but I found this trick

```
import org.mule.runtime.api.message.Message;

@MediaType(value = MediaType.ANY, strict = false)
public void myOperation(@Optional(defaultValue="#[message]") Object message) {
        
        if (message instanceof Message) {
            Message muleMessage = (Message) message;
            //Use muleMessage as you like :)
        }       
        
        
    }
```